# Accessing virtualbox webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, virtualbox

I want to access VirtualBox webservice using c#.
Firstly I created a service proxy using wsdl.exe and vboxwebService.wsdl file. '
Assuming that VirtualBox webservice is located in: http://localhost:18083/ how can I access it using c#?
I am doing something like this:

```
EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:18083/");
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
vboxPortTypeClient client = new vboxPortTypeClient(binding,endpoint);
```

and this works fine (I think):

But how then I then can get for instance version of virtualbox?
I don't know how to use the following method:

```
string test = string.Empty;
client.IVirtualBox_getVersion(test);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've managed to do what I was expecting
First of all I generated a new proxy class from two wsdl files

```
wsdl vboxService.wsdl vboxweb.wsdl
```

wsdl.exe then generated a proxy class named vboxService

then the following code does what I want:

```
vboxService service = new vboxService();
string oVirtualBox = service.IWebsessionManager_logon("", "");
service.IVirtualBox_Version(oVirtualBox);
```

Please note that for simplicity I disabled authentication for now - this is why I pass empty strings to IWebessionManager_logon method

Answer (score 8):

To those who ended up here from google with very little knowledge like me, vboxService.wsdl and vboxweb.wsdl are provided with [the Virtualbox SDK](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). Just download it and extract the files, you'll find them under sdk/bindings/webservice.